# Unable to avoid duplicate deletion in Apache Pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I am new to Apache Pig. I want to split and flatten the following input into my required output like who are all viewed that product.

My Input :(UserId, ProductId)

```
12345   123456,23456,987653  
23456   23456,123456,234567  
34567   234567,765678,987653
```

My Required Output:(ProductId, UserId)

```
123456  12345  
123456  23456  
23456   12345    
23456   23456  
987653  12345  
987653  34567  
234567  23456  
234567  34567  
765678  34567
```

My Pig Scripts:

```
 a = load '/home/hadoopuser/ips' using PigStorage('\t') as (key:chararray, val:chararray);  
 b = foreach a generate key as ky1, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(val)) as vl1;  
 c = group b by vl1;  
 d = foreach c generate group as vl2, $1 as ky2;  
 e = foreach d generate vl2, BagToString(ky2) as kyy;  
 f = foreach e generate vl2 as vl3,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(kyy,'_')) as ky3;  
 g = foreach f generate vl3, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(ky3)) as kk1; 
 dump g;
```

I got the following output which eliminates the repeated (duplicate)values,

```
(23456,12345)  
(123456,12345)  
(234567,23456)  
(765678,34567)  
(987653,12345)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? and how to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the second line of your code does exactly what you want, it simply displays the customer first and the product second. Put first the `FLATTEN` and then the `key` part:

```
a = load '/home/hadoopuser/ips' using PigStorage('\t') as (key:chararray, val:chararray);  
b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(val)) as ProductId, key as UserId;
dump b; 

(123456,12345)
(23456,12345)
(987653,12345)
(23456,23456)
(123456,23456)
(234567,23456)
(234567,34567)
(765678,34567)
(987653,34567)
```

As to why you are getting only one result per ProductId with your current code, you are grouping by ProductId, which gives you one row per different `ProductId` with a bag that contains all of the customers who viewed that product. Then, you convert that bag to a huge string separated by `_`, to convert it again to the same bag as before:

```
d = foreach c generate group as vl2, $1 as ky2;  
e = foreach d generate vl2, BagToString(ky2) as kyy;  
f = foreach e generate vl2 as vl3,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(kyy,'_')) as ky3;
```

The `BagToString` UDF converts a bag to a string, joining the different values in the bag separated by a custom delimiter, which defaults to `_`. In the next line, however, you split it by `_` resulting in the same bag as before. However, you `FLATTEN` that bag, so now instead of having a row with the ProductId and a bag, you have a row with several fields, being the first the ProductId, and the following fields all the customers that viewed the product:

**Before FLATTEN:**

```
(23456,{(23456,23456),(12345,23456)})
(123456,{(23456,123456),(12345,123456)})
(234567,{(34567,234567),(23456,234567)})
(765678,{(34567,765678)})
(987653,{(34567,987653),(12345,987653)})
```

**After FLATTEN:**

```
(23456,23456,23456,12345,23456)
(123456,23456,123456,12345,123456)
(234567,34567,234567,23456,234567)
(765678,34567,765678)
(987653,34567,987653,12345,987653)
```

And here lies the error. You have one only row for each of the products, and several fields in each row for each customer. When applying the last `foreach`, you select the first field (the product) and the second (the first of all the customers), discarding the rest of the customers on each row.

Comment: Hi Balduz, Thanks for your reply. It's working properly and I understood the problem very well by your clear explanation.